# Keeps on re-booting

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow

My Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime Plus keeps on restarting and showing message in Yellow in the top left corner "set warranty bit: kernel (0). How can I get it back to normal and to use my SD card as internal memory, because Phone memory too small for all the apps.

Comment: When did the problem start?

Comment: Thanks for reply. In the meantime I got my phone working again after I reinstalled the software. Now I'm battling to get the phone rooted. Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime + (G532F). I followed all instructions USB is debugged, OEM developer is open and is open for unknown sources. Used King Root. It goes well until 90% then stops with error message 'root failed' with error code 0x186269.